# How to send a key anonymously on a server through tor from command line?

Tags: proxy, tor, gnupg, proxychains

There are only few servers that are supporting key uploading from a tor node as given in the [sks servers list](https://sks-keyservers.net/status/).

**How would you suggest to send a key anonymously through tor from command line?**

I guess the following should make it

```
 service tor start
 proxychains gpg --send-keys --keyserver keyserver1.gnupg.pub <GPGKEY ID>
```

where `keyserver1.gnupg.pub` is a server supporting tor.